# Image not rendering properly

Tags: image, image-processing, amazon-s3

I'm attempting to parse an image that is possibly corrupt and it's driving me nuts trying to figure out what's wrong. Here is what I've deduced..

- Example image: https://s3.amazonaws.com/edison_new/ffb3ccc402d6bd6-original
- The images only show up in Chrome
- Can't drag them to the desktop (on a mac).
- Attempting to save them to computer yields a file that is "damaged or could not be open" when opening with Preview
- Attempting to open in Photoshop yields "Could not complete your request because an unknown or invalid JPEG marker type is found."
- Files are stored on Amazon S3
- The meta data indicates the content-type to be image/jpeg
- File definitely exists as you can see it in Chrome...

Anyone can help me deduce what is going on here??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image is in [WEBP](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/?csw=1) format, its not natively supported in IE or FF so will not be displayed.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=webp

(I opened it in IrfanView to see what format it was)